# How can I create a file by remote ssh from one Debian Virtual Machine to another, using expect nested in bash?

Tags: bash, ssh, debian, virtual-machine, expect

Im fairly new at Linux and I need to achieve this starting from the next structure:
Two Virtual Machines: A & B (Debian)

So that after executing one bash on A, a file gets created on B.

I have the next Expect file ("expectFile.exp"):

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
spawn ssh debian0@192.168.100.12
expect "password: "
send "Th3P4ssW0rd"
send "\r"
interact
```

Untill this point, when I execute "expect the bash establishes the ssh connection with no problem. But when I try to add the line, "spawn ssh root@..." before the "interact" line, and the bash turns this way:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
spawn ssh debian0@192.168.100.12
expect "password: "
send "Th3P4ssW0rd"
send "\r"
spawn ssh root@192.168.100.12 'bash-s' < test.sh
interact
```

I get asked for B machine password and gives me "Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password). Trying to solve this I changed the "/etc/ssh/sshd_config" file uncommenting #PassordAuthentication yes and #ChallengeResponseAuthentication no on B Machine, And finally restarting the SSH Service. But that didn't work

My plan is to make this expect file works and then nest its code into a bash file, so I can achieve the ssh connection and the BMachine side file creation in only one bash execution.

I've been kind of stucked in this problem, and I'd be glad to any suggestions.

Edit:
After using "ssh -vv command I get these lines":

```
"debug1: will attempt key: /home/debian1/.ssh/id_rsa" 
"debug1: will attempt key: /home/debian1/.ssh/id_dsa" 
"debug1: will attempt key: /home/debian1/.ssh/id_ecdsa" 
"debug1: will attempt key: /home/debian1/.ssh/id_ed25519" 
"debug1: will attempt key: /home/debian1/.ssh/id_xmss" 
"debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-keyex" "debug1: No valid key exchange context" 
"debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic" 
"debug1: Unspecified GSS failure. Minor code may provide more information No Kerberos credentials available (default cache: FILE:/tmp/krb55c_1000"x2 
"debug1: Next authentication method: publickey" 
"debug1: Trying private key: /home/debian1/.ssh/id_rsa" 
"debug1: Trying private key: /home/debian1/.ssh/id_dsa" 
"debug1: Trying private key: /home/debian1/.ssh/id_ecdsa" 
"debug1: Trying private key: /home/debian1/.ssh/id_ed25519" 
"debug1: Trying private key: /home/debian1/.ssh/id_xmss"
"debug1: Next authentication method: password root@192.168.100.12's password:" 
"debug2: we sent a password packet, wait for reply" 
"debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey, gssapi-keyex, gssapi-with-mic,password Permission denied please try again."
```

Comment: try ssh manually first and see if it works.

Comment: @sexpect-ExpectforShells Yes it does

Comment: use `ssh -vv` in the Expect script and see if there are useful info.

Comment: @sexpect-ExpectforShells I've edited the Question with the results of the ssh -vv